# PHP is it possible to catch "mod_fcgid: read data timeout in xxx seconds"

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch

```
[Sat Mar 18 23:49:53.686322 2023] [fcgid:warn] [pid 666060:tid 140024372713216] [client 82.33.142.192:10580] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 120 seconds
[Sat Mar 18 23:49:53.686380 2023] [fcgid:warn] [pid 666060:tid 140024372713216] (110)Connection timed out: [client 82.33.142.192:10580] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function
```

The question is basically in the title. Is it possible to catch this error in PHP? My script terminates prematurely.

```
function exception_error_handler($severity, $message, $file, $line) {
    throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $file, $line);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```

```
                $retryno = 0;
                do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents($url));
                    } 
                    catch(Throwable $t)
                    {
                        $retryno++;
                        continue;
                    }   
                    break;
                }while($retryno < $maxRetryCount);
```

Comment: Fcgi will forcibly terminate the script at the given timeout. You can't catch that inside that script because the script is no longer running when the error is emitted. Personally I'm using a very large fcgi timeout and using the PHP `max_execution_time` PHP.ini option to manage per script time. At least that way I can do `set_time_limit` to extend the script timeout if I need to.

Comment: @apokryfos thank you. That's exactly what I am doing (regarding script execution time). As the script is running on the shared server I have very limited admin rights there.